# Populate jQuery modal dialog form

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax, webforms

I have a application that contains a gridview. When a user selects one of the items from the gridview, I want to be able to show a jQuery dialog box that contains a form with some pre-filled information from the selected item from the gridview. Right now I have a div with some html text boxes that is set to be a modal dialog box. The user clicks on it, and the selected item's ID is easily to retrieve. The problem comes when I want to go out to the database, get some of the details, then pre-fill in some of the textboxes and other elements before displaying the dialog box to the user.

An easy comparison is having a user click on an item so that they can submit a form to be processed with some of the items from the selection already filled in. I was wondering what the easiest way to go about this is. Right now I have it so that selecting an item from the gridview uses jQuery to do a Ajax post with the ID to a [WebMethod] in the code behind where it can then go off the database and get all the details of the record. The problem is that for obvious reasons the WebMethod can't magically fill in the fields of the form. I could send back all of the information to the ajax query to fill in, but that also feels pretty messy because there is no real strong connection from the random data I send back and which field they belong to.

A lot of this is pondering out loud, but I am really interested in better understanding how to use jQuery and Ajax within ASP.NET.

Thank you for your help and your input.

Answer (score 0):

add an attribute on the gridview button:

```
  btn.Attributes.Add("onclick","ShowDialog();");
```

client script

```
 function ShowDialog(){
      //setup the dialog
$('#dialog).setup(function(){
   ......,
   buttons: "OK", function(){
     //save by calling btn2.click() where btn2 is a hidden button that handles save logic in server side
});
});
      $('#dialog').show();
    return false;
    });
```

Comment: The issue isn't the showing of the dialog, it is filling the dialog with a form that has some elements filled in from a database call. I want to know if there is a nice way to fill in these elements of the form instead of creating the html of the form on the ajax call.

Comment: yeah in fact the dialog shows html, therefore what you can do is to have a hidden div having your form and server controls inside it. you fill the fields on server side then use the dialog to show the div.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the server controls have to retrieve the information AFTER the initial page load. The page loads with a gridview where the user selects one, which will launch the modal dialog box. To fill in the information server side when the controls are hidden within a div on the page is that they cannot be filled in with server side programming dynamically when clicking on the gridview.